# Does S form a basis for R2?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, independence, invariant-subspace

I have a question here i can not explain my answer  **if it is right i do not sure**

Let S = {A = (a1, a2) , B = (a2, b2)} be a spanning set for R2
and some element x = (a, b) ∈ R2
We have x = c1 A + c2 B & x = c3 A + c4 B "**x has more than one representation**"
such that ( c1 ≠ c3 & c2 ≠ c4 )

Does S form a Basis for R2 ??

My Solution is no because the given of c1 ≠ c3 and c2 ≠ c4 make the S ***linearly dependent*** such that x must be equal to zero and the scalers are not equal so it has one condition of basis that it has A, B span but not linear independent where set to be basis it ***must have span and linearly independent*** when I search for equivalent solutions I found that any span equal to the dimension of vector space is ***linearly independent*** SO ... I don't know the right answer
**Any help?**

Comment: Indeed. A,B are not lineary independent and thus do not form a basis.

Comment: That what I see too but just I need to make sure if my answer is right, Thank you @FreeZe

Answer (score 1):

You can try to prove this much more general result(well a theorem rather) that given a set of $n$ vectors $\{v_{1},v_{2},...v_{n}\}$ . They form a basis for $V$ if and only if every vector $v$ in $V$ can be uniquely expressed as a linear combination of $v_{1},v_{2},...v_{n}$.

That is for any $v\in V$. If $v=\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}v_{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}d_{i}v_{i}$.

Then $c_{i}=d_{i}\,,\forall i=1,2,..n$.

Now it is easy to see that $\{v_{1},v_{2},...v_{n}\}$ generate the space, i.e $\text{span}(\{v_{1},v_{2},...v_{n}\})=V$.

and $0=\sum_{i=1}^{n}0\cdot v_{i}$.
Thus if $\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}v_{i}=0$ then $c_{i}=0\,,\forall i=1,2,...n$ by uniqueness assumption.
Hence $\{v_{1},v_{2},...v_{n}\}$ is a linearly independent spanning set and hence a basis.

Conversely if $\{v_{1},v_{2},...v_{n}\}$ is a basis then the representation is unique by Linear Independence . That is if $\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}v_{i}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}d_{i}v_{i}$ then $c_{i}-d_{i}=0$.

Comment: Yes that's nice it will help, I appreciate that, Thank you